# Page Control for Switching Between Views in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

My page controller passing images by moving images in the same way,if I want to click on page controller buttons the image should be change, like say suppose I have 3 images if I clicked on 3 page button on page controller the scroll view should jump to 3rd image.

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to change either image or page controller vice versa.its working only for images

Answer (score 0):

when you click on Pagecontroll then you will get its index with the help of this index you get which number on page button press the set cotentoffset or contentSize of your scrollview.

```
 [scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * yourpageIndex, scrollView.bounds.size.height)] ;
```

Comment: @user3122925 please search on Google there is lot of example and source code.